# How to draw shapes, lines, and arcs with c++

Tags: c++, windows-10, bgi

I'm working on a program that calculates the [Recaman Sequence.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGC5TdIiT9U) I'm trying to graph it by drawing arcs like in numberphile.

I've searched YouTube and there are videos on graphics.h. However, I've heard graphics.h is outdated. Is there a new thing similar to that? Is there another method, or should I try to install graphics.h? Also, I'm running this on a Windows 10 computer.

Comment: C++ by itself doesn't contain graphics support. You have to search for a graphics framework like SFML, Qt, ImGUI, etc.

Comment: GDI/GL/DirectX .... for simple drawings I would chose GDI  ...

Answer (score 0):

Install Dev c++.
Download these files:

```
https://github.com/SagarGaniga/Graphics-Library
```

Copy graphics.h and winbgim.h in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include
```

Copy libbgi.a in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib
```

Run Dev c++ and create new project. Then in menu > project > project option > parametrs tab:
Copy following in linker box and then ok:

```
-lbgi
-lgdi32
-lcomdlg32
-luuid
-loleaut32
-lole32
```

Test code:

```
#include <graphics.h>

    int main( )
    {
        initwindow(400, 300, "First Sample");
        circle(100, 50, 40);
        while (!kbhit( ))
        {
            delay(200);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I abandoned this project, so I'm not going to try out your solution, sorry. Hopefully your answer will help others who come to this question.